# Insert an icon into table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this.I need to update second cell(td) with an icon whenever tr id matches with server number.I have done that part.please check the code but I am not able to put an icon n second column (second td) after div.My jquery codes and table structre given below.This code put the icon in first column.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);


            $.map(obj.locked, function (id) {
                $("#grid-table tr#" + id)
                    .find("input[type=checkbox]")
                    .after($("<img src='http://www.placehold.it/20x10/ff0000'>"));
                });


<table>
<tr id='1'>
<td>checckbox here</td>
<td><div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span></div></td>
<td>anothe text</td>
</tr>

<tr id='2'>
<td>checckbox here</td>
<td><div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span></div></td>
<td>anothe text</td>
</tr>

<tr id='3'>
<td>checckbox here</td>
<td><div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span></div></td>
<td>anothe text</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$.map(obj.locked, function (id) {
    $("#grid-table tr#" + id)
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .closest('td')
        .next('td').html("<img src='http://www.placehold.it/20x10/ff0000'>");
    });
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#grid-table tr#1")
        .find("input[type=checkbox]")
        .closest('td')
        .next('td')
        .html("<img src='http://www.placehold.it/20x10/ff0000'>");
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid-table">
  <tr id='1'>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>anothe text</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='2'>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>anothe text</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id='3'>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-original-title="UnLocked" class="ui-pg-div"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-unlock"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>anothe text</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I have a question regarding this item,If I want to put an another Icon in next colum,I can't use next() function in jquery ?

Comment: @aniltc, You can use `$("#grid-table tr#" + id).find('td').eq(index)`